# combining oracle sql AND OR queries in Codeigniter using oci8 database drivers

Tags: php, database, oracle, codeigniter, oci8

I am using codeigniter OCI8 database drivers can anybody help me how to  use `$this->db->group_start()`.

If this not work in oci8 then any alternate option
I am using ajax based datatables.

On page load datatables works but in case of search datatable return this error

> **Fatal error**:  Call to undefined method CI_DB_oci8_driver::group_start()

here is my code

```
function _get_datatables_query(){
    $this->db->from($this->table);

    $i = 0;

    foreach($this->column_search as $item){
        if(strtoupper($_POST['search']['value'])) // if datatable send POST for search
        {
            if($i===0) // first loop
            {
                $this->db->group_start();
                $this->db->like($item, strtoupper($_POST['search']['value']));
            }
            else
            {
                $this->school_db->or_like($item, strtoupper($_POST['search']['value']));
            }
            $this->db->group_end();
          //  if(count($this->column_search) - 1 == $i) //last loop
             //   $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
        }
        $i++;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
    {
        $this->db->order_by($this->column_order[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
    }
    else if(isset($this->order))
    {
        $order = $this->order;
        $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: I am using ajax based datatables 
I want to combine AND OR queries when I search from datatables

Comment: Check your Codeigniter version if it is 2.* then group_start/end won't be available, else it should be work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've no idea which error gets thrown - but your function won't work that way - try the following instead

```
function _get_datatables_query()
{
    $this->db->from($this->table);

    $this->db->group_start();
    foreach($this->column_search as $item)
    {
        if(strtoupper($_POST['search']['value'])) // if datatable send POST for search
        {
            $this->db->or_like($item, strtoupper($_POST['search']['value']));
        }
    }
    $this->db->group_end();

    if(isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
    {
        $this->db->order_by($this->column_order[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
    }
    else if(isset($this->order))
    {
        $order = $this->order;
        $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this but not work. If I comment   $this->db->group_start(); and  $this->db->group_end(); datatables work fine but in case of search data won't filter properly

Comment: In case of search I get this error <b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined method CI_DB_oci8_driver::group_start()

Comment: the main problem is - you didn't even mention this error in your question - can you please update your question accordingly - otherwise I'm just out here for fishing,,,

Answer (score 1):

I have Solved this problem with some custom coding. 
I just put Like in Where clause

$this->db->where("(" .$item . " LIKE '%".strtoupper($_POST['search']['value']."%'"));

Here is solution that work for me

```
private function _get_datatables_query()
{

    $this->db->from($this->table);

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($this->column_search as $item)
    {
        if(strtoupper($_POST['search']['value'])) // if datatable send POST for search
        {
            if($i===0) // first loop
            {
                if(count($this->column_search) > 1)
                    $this->db->where("(" .$item . " LIKE '%".strtoupper($_POST['search']['value']."%'"));
                else
                    $this->db->where("(" .$item . " LIKE '%".strtoupper($_POST['search']['value']."%')"));
            }
            else
            {
                if(count($this->column_search) - 1 == $i)
                    $this->db->or_where($item . " LIKE '%".strtoupper($_POST['search']['value']."%')"));
                else
                    $this->db->or_where($item . " LIKE '%".strtoupper($_POST['search']['value']."%'"));
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
    {
        $this->db->order_by($this->column_order[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
    }
    else if(isset($this->order))
    {
        $order = $this->order;

        $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
    }
}
```